# MSbuild Command Line throws Error for Nuget package, Visual studio does not

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, msbuild, nuget

I am using MSbuild version 16.11.1.47101 from the command line to compile a project. When I do this, I get an error that states

```
"C:\Repos\Vi8.Ipc.Server\Code\vi8.server.core\vi8.server.core.csproj" (clean;rebuild target) (1) ->
       (EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports target) ->
         C:\Repos\Vi8.Ipc.Server\Code\vi8.server.core\vi8.server.core.csproj(214,5): error : This project references Nu
       Get package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more informat
       ion, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Con
       figuration.UserSecrets.5.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.props.
```

Indeed at the ..\packages location, this entire package is missing while all the others are present.

1. When I delete the ..\packages folder and use MsBuild with restore, it copies all packages to the ..\package location, except for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets and then fails.
2. When I compile this using Visual Studio, the compilation succeeds. VS also copies all packages to the ..\package location except for this Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets package however VS seems to reference all packages from C:\Users{UserName}.nuget\packages folder

I really do need to compile this from the command line. Any help is appreciated!

What is weird is that when I compile this using Visual Studio, the compilation succeeds. Visual Studio seems to reference this package from

Comment: Is your project based on .NET Core, or .NET Framework? Can this NuGet package be successfully installed by using VS IDE > NuGet Package Manager?

Comment: It's .net 4.7.2 Framework based project. Since I am using PackageReference format,  Visual Studio doesn't show this in the References node as this is not a top level package itself. However from within VS I am able to successfully build and run this project. It's the command line MSBuild where the problem lies.

Comment: What do you mean about "using PackageReference" format? Change to `PackageReference` in Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General > Package Management > `Default package management format`?

Comment: Yes exactly. This project doesn't use packages.config. Thus the References node only shows top level dependencies and not the entire dependency tree.

Comment: I worked around by compiling the solution file directly. somehow compiling project files give this error but not when I compile Solution files. I will leave this question unanswered for a few days to see if someone else can answer it. Else will close it